# Converting a table in one form to another using Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to load a CSV file into Snowflake. The sample format of the input csv table in s3 location is as follows (with 2 columns: ID, Location_count):
[Input csv table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wbIg.png)

I  need to transform it in the below format:(with 3 columns:ID, Location, Count)
[Output csv table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49CES.png)

However when I am trying to load the input file using the following query after creating database, external stage and file format, it  returns LOAD_FAILED

create or replace table *table_name*
(
id integer,
Location_count variant
);

select  parse_json(Location_count) as c;

list @*stage_name*;
copy into *table_name* from @*stage_name* file_format = '*fileformatname*' on_error = 'continue';

Comment: Can you please share your code for creating the external stage and the file-format as well as the full error message?

Comment: You can check if it is a data error by using the VALIDATION_MODE, of the COPY into snowflake command https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html

Answer (score 0):

you will probably need to parse_json that 2nd column as part of a copy-transformation.  For example:

create file format myformat
type = csv field_delimiter = ','
FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '"';

create or replace stage csv_stage file_format = (format_name = myformat);

copy into @csv_stage from
( select '1',
'{"SHS-TRN":654738,"PRN-UTN":78956,"NCT-JHN":96767}') ;

create or replace table blah (id integer, something variant);

copy into blah from (select $1, parse_json($2) from @csv_stage);